# Prove that when $\frac{x_n}{y_n}$ converges, then it does not imply, that $\frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{y_{n+1}-y_n}$

Tags: limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

The tasks sounds like this:

Given sequences $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ where $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=0$. It is also known, that $y_n$ is strong monoton. Show that when $$\frac{x_n}{y_n}$$ converges for $n\to\infty$, then it does not imply, that $$\frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{y_{n+1}-y_n}$$ for $n\to\infty$ also converges

---

With a little help I got this:

1. $a_n=\frac{x_n}{y_n}$, obviously $a_n\overset{n\to\infty}{\to}\alpha$
2. $\frac{x_{n+1} - x_n}{y_{n+1} - y_n} = \frac{a_{n+1} y_{n+1} - a_n y_n}{y_{n+1} - y_n} = \frac{(a_{n+1} y_{n+1} - a_n y_{n+1}) + (a_n y_{n+1} - a_n y_n)}{y_{n+1} - y_n} = \frac{(a_{n+1} y_{n+1} - a_n y_{n+1})}{y_{n+1} - y_n} + a_n = \frac{y_{n+1} (a_{n+1} - a_n)}{y_{n+1} - y_n} + a_n$
3. If we want to make this expression convergent, then we suppose, that:$$\frac{y_{n+1}(a_{n+1}-a_n)}{y_{n+1}-y_n}\to\beta$$
4. Let $y=\frac{1}{n}$, then $$\frac{\frac{1}{n+1}(\frac{x_{n+1}}{\frac{1}{n+1}}-\frac{x_n}{\frac{1}{n}})}{\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n}}=-n(n\cdot x_{n+1}+ x_{n+1}-n\cdot x_n)$$ and if we make $n$ infinitely big, we have $-\infty(\infty\cdot0+0-\infty\cdot0)$ what looks like bad to me.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: You're not supposed to show that $\left\{\frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{y_{n+1}-y_n}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ diverges (because it doesn't necessarily), but you're supposed to show that it *can* diverge, meaning you have to produce an example where it does

Comment: @Lorago, do you mean I just have to try different combinations of $x_n$ and $y_n$ sequences? I mean, I would like to do it mathematically correct, but if it is the only way to prove the solution, then okay

Comment: As another comment says, you seem to be missunderstanding how to disprove a for all statement: To disprove a for all statement, you need to find a counterexample. The strategy should be to find specific sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ for which the fraction in the question does not converge (either because  it goes to infinity, or because it has multiple limit points).

Comment: @AkshatMishra, the $y_n$ is strong monoton, so $y_{n+1}\neq y_{n}$

Comment: @AkshatMishra The constant nonzero  sequence does not converge to $0.$

Comment: Take $x_n=(-1)^n$ and $y_n=n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y_n={1\over n},$  $x_{2n}={1\over 2n}$ and $x_{2n+1}={1\over 2n}-{1\over  2(n+1)^4}.$ Then $y_n$ is strictly decreasing. By the way the $x_n$ is decreasing as well. The sequence ${x_n\over y_n}$ tends to $1.$ Moreover $$ {x_{2n+1}-x_{2n}\over y_{2n+1}-y_{2n}}$$ is convergent  to $0,
$ while $${x_{2n}-x_{2n-1}\over y_{2n}-y_{2n-1}}$$ tends to $1.$

Comment: Could you please explain where did you get the idea of using only even numbers in $y_{2n}=\frac{1}{2n}$. So technically previous expression means, that $x_n=y_n=\frac{1}{n}$? And could you please describe how you got $y_{2n+1}$ equation?

Comment: I wanted to get $x_{2n}=y_{2n}.$ Besides my aim was to make the behaviors of the increments $y_{2n}-y_{2n+}$ and $y_{2n+1}-y_{2n+2}$ to behave differently. Namely the first small and the second large.

Comment: Why especially $x_{2n}=y_{2n}$ and not just $x_{n}=y_{n}$?

Comment: The claim $x_n=y_n$ does not lead to a counterexample as $x_{n+1}-x_n=y_{n+1}-y_n,$ so the divided difference is equal $1.$  In order to spoil the convergence of the divided difference we cannot take $x_n=y_n.$

Comment: @John Bentin Thanks for upvoting. I had to delete my answers many times, especially when I was answering while watching tennis tournaments at the same time.